# File upload (Yii)

Tags: php, upload, yii

I'm implementing some file uploading fields and i'm having some difficulties with it.
I was following this [article](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/2/) and everything was perfect until I tried to update my model.
If I didn't fill the file field, it was cleared after save. I was googling and find this [topic](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/5419-optional-upload-file-when-update-a-record/). I've modified my code, but now, when I try to modify another field, it isn't save, unless I modify the image field too. 
Where's the problem? 
My model code:

```
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Company']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Company'];
            $the_image = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
            if (is_object($the_image) && get_class($the_image)==='CUploadedFile')
              $model->image = $the_image;
            if($model->save())
                if (is_object($the_image))
                $model->image->saveAs(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot') . '/upload/' . $model->image);
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('update',array(
            'model'=>$model,
    }
```

And these are the rules in my model:

```
            array('name', 'required'),
            array('type, number, rating, user_id', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            array('name, image, address, site, mail', 'length', 'max'=>1000),
            array('text', 'safe'),
            array('image', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, gif, png'),
            array('image', 'unsafe'),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('id, type, name, text, address, site, mail, number, rating, user_id', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
```

Please, help me. I have no clue why it isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try modifying your `image` attribute rule on the Update [scenario](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/266/understanding-scenarios/) like this:

```php
array('image', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, gif, png','allowEmpty' => true, 'on'=>'update'),
```

I found this tip [here](http://www.yiichina.net/forum/index.php/topic/19924-update-image/), hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function uploadMultifile ($model,$attr,$path)
        {
            if($sfile=CUploadedFile::getInstances($model, $attr)){
              foreach ($sfile as $i=>$file){  
                 $formatName=time().$i.'.'.$file->getExtensionName();
                 $file->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath  .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..'. $path.$formatName);
                     //  $model->image->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath . '/../studentimage/' . $date . $model->image);
                 $ffile[$i]=$formatName;
                 }
                return ($ffile);
             }
         }

public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new Subject;
    // $model->date_erected = date('Y-m-d');
    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Subject']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Subject'];
                    if($filez=$this->uploadMultifile($model,'imagea','/../images/views/'))
                {
                    $model->documents=implode(",", $filez);
                }
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

Comment: When answering questions, it would be nice if you called out what was changed.